# UISegmentController title text is cutting weirdly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, word-wrap

[image]

see above attached image.

It's programatically written in Objective-C. UISegmentController is cutting title text.

Weird thing is, it shows '**Privacy Policy**' full text which is way longer than '**About**' and '**Terms**', which is cutting.

Can anybody please help in this?

code is given below:

```
    UISegmentedControl *unitsPicker                     = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"About", @"Terms", @"Privacy Policy"]];
    unitsPicker.frame                   = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(unitsLabel.frame) + kBottomPaddingConstant, CGRectGetWidth(_unitsContainer.frame), segmentHeightConstant);
    unitsPicker.autoresizingMask        = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    unitsPicker.selectedSegmentIndex    = ![TemperatureUtility unitIsCelsius];
    [unitsPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(onUnitPickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    unitsPicker.layer.cornerRadius   = 5.0f;
    unitsPicker.layer.borderColor    = [UIColorFromRGB(0xE9E9E9) CGColor];
    unitsPicker.layer.borderWidth    = 1.0f;
    unitsPicker.layer.masksToBounds  = YES;
    unitsPicker.clipsToBounds        = YES;
    [_unitsContainer addSubview:unitsPicker];
```

Comment: "It's programatically written in Objective-C." Then show us the program, please. Show your code!

Comment: There is nothing specially I did in code that's why I didn't put it. But still now I updated with my code.

Comment: Try calling `sizeToFit` on your segmented control.

Comment: @BARS - are you sure that's the only code you have that affects it? Running your code pretty much as-is, I get this result: https://imgur.com/a/VCyzHYx

Answer (score 2):

Try setting:

`segmentedControl.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;`

From the docs:

> If the value of this property is true, for segments whose width value is 0, the control attempts to adjust segment widths based on their content widths.
>   The default is false.

Comment: You may be forcing the total width with your other code above. Try removing the code where you set the frame of the segmentedControl, and maybe clipsToBounds as well. You should look at AutoLayout to position your control.

Comment: I'm not forcing for width. and you can see in attached image, it's showing **Privacy Policy** as full string but not **About**. All 3 segments are having equal width.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 and 5+ Solution
Add

```
mySegmentController.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
```

inside viewDidLoad() {}